# Creating a card Game of Set in JavaFX

Tags: java, user-interface, javafx

I am creating a game of Set with JavaFX but am running into a few issues.

1. I'm currently getting an out of bounds exception when I try to select a card in the 4th column (or if I use the add 3 function and try to click on one of those cards)
2. Also, when I click three cards and they are not a set, I want to reset the backgrounds to be white and be able to start over/select three new cards
3. If it is a set, I want to remove those cards from the board and replace them with three new cards

Any help would be appreciated! I've been so stuck on this and cannot find any resources to point me in the right direction.

GameFX

```
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.geometry.Insets;
import javafx.scene.Node;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.Label;
import javafx.scene.layout.*;
import javafx.scene.paint.Color;
import javafx.stage.Stage;
import javafx.scene.shape.*;
import javafx.scene.layout.Pane;
import javafx.scene.layout.Background;
import javafx.scene.layout.BackgroundFill;
import javafx.scene.layout.CornerRadii;
import javafx.scene.transform.Rotate;
import javafx.scene.text.*;
import javafx.scene.image.Image;
import javafx.scene.paint.ImagePattern;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import javafx.scene.control.Button;
import javafx.scene.layout.HBox;
import javafx.application.Platform;
import javafx.event.ActionEvent;
import javafx.geometry.Insets;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.event.EventHandler;
import javafx.scene.input.MouseEvent;

public class GameFX extends Application {
    public Game g;
    private Pane pane;
    private Board b;
    //int rows = g.getBoard().numRows();
    //int cols = g.getBoard().numCols();

    public static void main(String [] args) {
        Application.launch((String[]) args);
    }

    public void start(Stage stage) throws Exception {

        // Variables
        g = new Game();
        b = g.getBoard();
        pane = new Pane();
        int cardsLeft = g.deck.deck.size();
        BackgroundFill grayBG = new BackgroundFill(Color.LIGHTGRAY, new CornerRadii(1), new Insets(0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0));
        BackgroundFill darkGrayBG = new BackgroundFill(Color.DARKGRAY, new CornerRadii(1), new Insets(0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0));
        BorderPane main = new BorderPane();
        Scene scene = new Scene(main);
        Label label = new Label("Set Game");
        Label instructionsLabel = new Label("Click on cards to select them, Double-click to deselect them, type 'A' to add three cards, type 'E' to end the game");
        Label actionsLabel = new Label("(A)dd 3 cards, (E)nd Game, (N)ew Game");
        Label cardsRemaining = new Label("There are " + cardsLeft + " cards remaining in the deck");
        GridPane topPane = new GridPane();
        GridPane centerPane = new GridPane();
        GridPane rightPane = new GridPane();
        GridPane bottomPane = new GridPane();

        int rows = g.getBoard().numRows();
        int cols = g.getBoard().numCols();

        boolean stop = false;

        // Configure pane
        pane.setPrefHeight(500);
        pane.setPrefWidth(1000);
        centerPane.setPrefHeight(500);
        centerPane.setPrefWidth(700);
        rightPane.setPrefWidth(300);
        rightPane.setPrefHeight(500);
        pane.setBackground(new Background(grayBG));
        rightPane.setBackground(new Background(darkGrayBG));

        // Create initial board
        updateBoard(b, centerPane);

        // Configure label
        label.setTextFill(Color.RED);

        // Add content to topPane
        topPane.add(label, 0, 0);
        topPane.add(instructionsLabel, 0, 1);
        topPane.add(actionsLabel, 0, 2);
        topPane.add(cardsRemaining, 0, 3);

        // Set panes in BorderPane layout
        main.setCenter(centerPane);
        main.setTop(topPane);
        //main.setRight(rightPane); 

        // Request focus and configure window
        stage.setTitle("Set");
        stage.setScene(scene);
        stage.show();
        centerPane.requestFocus();
        centerPane.setOnKeyPressed(e -> {
            switch (e.getCode()) {
                case A: {
                    System.out.println("A was pressed");
                    if (b.numCols() < 6) {
                        g.add3();
                    }
                    updateBoard(b, centerPane);
                    break;
                }
                case E: {
                  Platform.exit();
                  break;
                }
                case N: {
                  System.out.println( "New Game!" );
                  stage.close();
                  Game g2 = new Game();
                  Board  b2 = g2.getBoard();
                  updateBoard(b2, centerPane);
                  stage.setScene(scene);
                  stage.show();
                }
            }
        });
    }


    public Pane createCard(int shape, int fill, int color, int number, int rows, int cols) {
         //int cardRow = cardRow;
         //int cardColumn = cardColumn;
         Pane cardPane = new Pane();
         Pane shapePane = new Pane();

         ArrayList<Rectangle> squares = new ArrayList<Rectangle>();
         ArrayList<Circle> circles = new ArrayList<Circle>();
         ArrayList<Rectangle> diamonds = new ArrayList<Rectangle>();


         String stripesRedURL = "stripesRed.png";
         String stripesPurpleURL = "stripesPurple.png";
         String stripesGreenURL = "stripesGreen.png";
         Image stripesRed = new Image(stripesRedURL);
         Image stripesPurple = new Image(stripesPurpleURL);
         Image stripesGreen = new Image(stripesGreenURL);

        BackgroundFill cardBG = new BackgroundFill(Color.WHITE,
                new CornerRadii(1),
                new Insets(0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0));

         if (shape == 0) {
             for (int i=0; i < number; i++) {
                 circles.add(new Circle(50,20 + (i * 30),10));
             }

             for(Circle circle: circles) {
                 if (fill == 0) {
                     if (color == 0) {
                         circle.setFill(Color.RED);
                     } else if (color == 1) {
                         circle.setFill(Color.PURPLE);
                     } else if (color == 2) {
                         circle.setFill(Color.GREEN);
                     }
                 } else if (fill == 1) {
                     if (color == 0) {
                         circle.setFill(new ImagePattern(stripesRed, 0, 0, 40, 40, false));
                     } else if (color == 1) {
                         circle.setFill(new ImagePattern(stripesPurple, 0, 0, 40, 40, false));
                     } else if (color == 2) {
                         circle.setFill(new ImagePattern(stripesGreen, 0, 0, 40, 40, false));
                     }
                 } else if (fill == 2) {
                     if (color == 0) {
                         circle.setStroke(Color.RED);
                         circle.setFill(Color.WHITE);
                     } else if (color == 1) {
                         circle.setStroke(Color.PURPLE);
                         circle.setFill(Color.WHITE);
                     } else if (color == 2) {
                         circle.setStroke(Color.GREEN);
                         circle.setFill(Color.WHITE);
                     }
                 }
             }
             //System.out.println(circles);
             for(Circle circle: circles) {
                 shapePane.getChildren().add(circle);
             }
         } else if (shape == 1) {
             for (int i=0; i < number; i++) {
                 squares.add(new Rectangle(40, 10 + (i * 30), 20, 20));
             }

             for(Rectangle square: squares) {
                 if (fill == 0) {
                     if (color == 0) {
                         square.setFill(Color.RED);
                     } else if (color == 1) {
                         square.setFill(Color.PURPLE);
                     } else if (color == 2) {
                         square.setFill(Color.GREEN);
                     }
                 } else if (fill == 1) {
                     if (color == 0) {
                         square.setFill(new ImagePattern(stripesRed, 0, 0, 40, 40, false));
                     } else if (color == 1) {
                         square.setFill(new ImagePattern(stripesPurple, 0, 0, 40, 40, false));
                     } else if (color == 2) {
                         square.setFill(new ImagePattern(stripesGreen, 0, 0, 40, 40, false));
                     }
                 } else if (fill == 2) {
                     if (color == 0) {
                         square.setStroke(Color.RED);
                         square.setFill(Color.WHITE);
                     } else if (color == 1) {
                         square.setStroke(Color.PURPLE);
                         square.setFill(Color.WHITE);
                     } else if (color == 2) {
                         square.setStroke(Color.GREEN);
                         square.setFill(Color.WHITE);
                     }
                 }
             }
             //System.out.println(squares);
             for(Rectangle square: squares) {
                 shapePane.getChildren().add(square);
             }
         } else if (shape == 2) {
             for (int i=0; i < number; i++) {
                 diamonds.add(new Rectangle(40, 10 + (i * 30), 20, 20));
             }

             for(Rectangle diamond: diamonds) {
                 diamond.getTransforms().add(new Rotate(45,50,50));
                 if (fill == 0) {
                     if (color == 0) {
                         diamond.setFill(Color.RED);
                     } else if (color == 1) {
                         diamond.setFill(Color.PURPLE);
                     } else if (color == 2) {
                         diamond.setFill(Color.GREEN);
                     }
                 } else if (fill == 1) {
                     if (color == 0) {
                         diamond.setFill(new ImagePattern(stripesRed, 0, 0, 40, 40, false));
                     } else if (color == 1) {
                         diamond.setFill(new ImagePattern(stripesRed, 0, 0, 40, 40, false));
                     } else if (color == 2) {
                         diamond.setFill(new ImagePattern(stripesRed, 0, 0, 40, 40, false));
                     }
                 } else if (fill == 2) {
                     if (color == 0) {
                         diamond.setStroke(Color.RED);
                         diamond.setFill(Color.WHITE);
                     } else if (color == 1) {
                         diamond.setStroke(Color.PURPLE);
                         diamond.setFill(Color.WHITE);
                     } else if (color == 2) {
                         diamond.setStroke(Color.GREEN);
                         diamond.setFill(Color.WHITE);
                     }
                 }

             }
             //System.out.println(diamonds);
             for(Rectangle diamond: diamonds) {
                 shapePane.getChildren().add(diamond);
             }
         }
        cardPane.setBackground(new Background(cardBG));
        cardPane.setBorder(new Border(new BorderStroke(Color.BLACK, BorderStrokeStyle.SOLID, CornerRadii.EMPTY, BorderWidths.DEFAULT)));
        cardPane.setPrefHeight(100);
        cardPane.setPrefWidth(100);
        cardPane.getChildren().addAll(shapePane);

        //If card is selected, background changes color
        cardPane.setOnMouseClicked(new EventHandler<MouseEvent>(){
        //int selected = 0;
        //ArrayList<String> selected = new ArrayList<String>();
        //g.getSelected();;


        @Override
            public void handle(MouseEvent me) {
               g.board.getBoardSquare(rows,cols).setSelected(!g.board.getBoardSquare(rows,cols).isSelected());
               if(me.getClickCount() == 1){
                  cardPane.setBackground(new Background(new BackgroundFill(Color.LIGHTGRAY, CornerRadii.EMPTY, Insets.EMPTY)));
                  g.addToSelected(rows, cols);
               }
               else if(me.getClickCount() == 2){
                  cardPane.setBackground(new Background(new BackgroundFill(Color.WHITE, CornerRadii.EMPTY, Insets.EMPTY)));
                  g.removeSelected(rows, cols);
               }
               if(g.numSelected()==3){
                  g.testSelected();
                  if(g.testSelected() == true){
                     System.out.println("Remove and replace");
                  }
                  else if(g.testSelected() == false){
                     System.out.println("Background to white");
                  }
                  //entire back board to white
                  //cardPane.setBackground(new Background(new BackgroundFill(Color.WHITE, CornerRadii.EMPTY, Insets.EMPTY)));
               }
            }
        });

        return cardPane;

     }

     public void updateBoard(Board b, GridPane pane) {
         ArrayList<ArrayList<BoardSquare>> boardSquares = b.getBoardSquares();
         for (ArrayList<BoardSquare> boardRow: boardSquares) {
             for (BoardSquare boardSquare: boardRow) {
                 Card boardCard = boardSquare.getCard();
                 pane.add(createCard(boardCard.getShape(), boardCard.getShading(), boardCard.getColor(), boardCard.getNumber() + 1, boardSquare.getRow(), boardSquare.getColumn()), boardSquare.getRow(), boardSquare.getColumn());
             }   
         }
      }

}
```

Game

```
import java.util.ArrayList;


public class Game{
   //intialize variable, deck and board, arraylist
   private int selectedCards;
   Deck deck;
   Board board;
   private ArrayList <BoardSquare> selected;

   /*
   Constructor
   creates a new game with a new shuffled deck
   and board, selected starts empty
   */
   public Game(){
      selectedCards = 0;
      deck = new Deck();
      deck.shuffle();
      board = new Board(deck);
      selected = new ArrayList<BoardSquare>(3);
   }

   /*
   method outOfCards determines if the 
   board is out of new cards
   @return boolean out
   */
   public boolean outOfCards(){
      boolean out;
      if(deck.isEmpty() == true){
         out = true;
      }
      else
      {
         out = false;
      }
      return out;
   }

   /*
   method addToSelected
   takes the BoardSquare the user selects and saves it to compare later
   @param row
   @param column
   */
   public void addToSelected(int row, int col){
   //add card to an arraylist of selected
      selected.add(board.getBoardSquare(row, col));
      selectedCards++;
      if (selectedCards == 3){
         testSelected();
         }
   }

   /*
   method numSelected returns the number of selected cards being held
   @return selectedCards
   */
   public int numSelected(){
      return selectedCards;
   }

   /*
   method testSelected
   tests whether the three cards in the selected ArrayList
   are a Set
   */
   public boolean testSelected(){
      boolean set = false;
   //test if the cards from selected are a Set, method is in Card Class
      if (selected.size() == 3 && !selected.isEmpty()){
         //boolean set = false;
         //BoardSquare bs1 = selected.get(0);
         //BoardSquare bs2 = selected.get(1);
         //BoardSquare bs3 = selected.get(2);
         //Card.isSet(bs1.getCard(), bs2.getCard(), bs2.getCard());
         if (Card.isSet(selected.get(0).getCard(), selected.get(1).getCard(), selected.get(2).getCard())){
            board.replaceCard(deck.getTopCard(), selected.get(0).getRow(), selected.get(0).getColumn());
            board.replaceCard(deck.getTopCard(), selected.get(1).getRow(), selected.get(1).getColumn());
            board.replaceCard(deck.getTopCard(), selected.get(2).getRow(), selected.get(2).getColumn());
            //print SET
            System.out.print("It's a SET! Pick another\n");
            //empty ArrayList
            for (int i = 0; i < selected.size();) {
               selectedCards = 0;
               selected.remove(i);
            }
             set = true;
         }
         else{
            //print NOT a SET
            System.out.print("Not a SET! Try again\n");
            //empty ArrayList
            for (int i = 0; i < selected.size();) {
               selectedCards = 0;
               selected.remove(i);
            }
            set = false;
         }
         //return set;
      }
      return set;
   }

   /*
   method removeSelected
   de-selects a boardsquare from the arraylist
   @param row
   @param column
   */
   public void removeSelected(int row, int col){
      boolean status = false;
      if (selected.get(0).getRow() == row && selected.get(0).getColumn() == col){
         selected.remove(0);
         selectedCards--;
      }
      else if (selected.get(1).getRow() == row && selected.get(1).getColumn() == col){
         selected.remove(1);
         selectedCards--;
      }
      else if (selected.get(2).getRow() == row && selected.get(2).getColumn() == col){
         selected.remove(2);
         selectedCards--;
      }
      else{
         status = false;
      }
   }

   /*
   method getSelected
   returns the cards that have been selected
   @return selected
   */
   public ArrayList<BoardSquare> getSelected(){
      return selected;
   }

   /*
   method add3
   adds three cards to the board
   */
   public void add3(){
      board.add3(deck);
   }

   /*
   method to String
   converts the game to a string for printing
   */
   public String toString(){
      return board.toString();
   }


   public Board getBoard() {
      return board;
   }
}
```

Board

```
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class Board{
   //initialize arraylist and variables
   private ArrayList<ArrayList<BoardSquare>> board;
   public final static int INITIAL_ROWS = 3;
   public final static int INITIAL_COLS = 4;

   //Constructor that accepts a Deck object and populates
   //The ArrayLists
   public Board(Deck deck){
      board = new ArrayList<ArrayList<BoardSquare>>();
      ArrayList<Card> boardsquare;
      for(int i=0; i<3; i++){
         board.add(new ArrayList<BoardSquare>());
         for(int j=0; j<4; j++){
            board.get(i).add(new BoardSquare(deck.getTopCard(),i,j));
         }
      }           
   }

   /*
   method replaceCard will replace a card that has been removed
   @param card - card object
   @param row - row of the card
   @param column - column of card
   */
   public void replaceCard(Card card, int row, int column){
      board.get(row).get(column).setCard(card);
   }

   /*
   method getBoardSquare returns the card at a specified location
   @param row
   @param column
   @return reference to a board square location
   */
   public BoardSquare getBoardSquare(int row, int column){
      return board.get(row).get(column);
   }

   public ArrayList<ArrayList<BoardSquare>> getBoardSquares() {
      return board;
   }

   /*
   method add3 puts one card into each row if no sets are available
   @param deck object
   */
   public void add3(Deck deck){
      for(int i=0; i<3; i++) {
         board.get(i).add(new BoardSquare(deck.getTopCard(),i,board.get(i).size()));
      }
   }


   /*
   method getCard returns a reference to a card at a location
   @param row
   @param column
   @return reference to a card
   */
   public Card getCard(int row, int column){
      return board.get(row).get(column).getCard();
   }

   /*
   method numRows returns amount of rows on the board
   @return rows
   */
   public int numRows(){
      return INITIAL_ROWS;
   }

   /*
   method numCols gets how many columns in each row, intially 4
   @return columns aka size of the column array
   */
   public int numCols(){
      return board.get(0).size();
   }

   /*
   method toString returns a String representation of the Board
   @return str
   */
   public String toString(){
      String str = "";
      for(int i=0; i<3; i++){
         for(int j=0; j<numCols(); j++){
            str += (board.get(i).get(j).getCard().toString() + "\t");
         }
         str += "\n";
      }
      return str;
   }
}
```

BoardSquare

```
public class BoardSquare{

   private int column;//column of the card
   private int row; //row of the card
   private Card card;
   private boolean selected=false;

   /*Constructor
   @param card, a card object
   @param column, column of the card
   @param row, row of the card
   */
   public BoardSquare(Card card, int column, int row){
      this.column = column;
      this.row = row;
      this.card = card;
   }

   /*
   method getColumn returns column
   @return column
   */
   public int getColumn(){
      return column;
   }

   /*
   method setColumn updates the column
   @param c
   */
   public void setColumn(int c){
      column = c;
   }

   /*
   method getRow returns row
   @return row
   */
   public int getRow(){
      return row;
   }

   /*
   method setRow updates the row
   @param r
   */
   public void setRow(int r){
      row = r;
   }

   /*
   method getCard returns card
   @return card
   */
   public Card getCard(){
      return card;
   }

   /*
   method setCard updates the card
   @param c
   */
   public void setCard(Card c){
      card = c;
   }

   /*
   method isSelected
   @returns boolean selected
   */
   public boolean isSelected(){
      return selected;
   }

   public void setSelected(boolean s){
      selected = s;
   }

}
```

Deck

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Random;

public class Deck{
   //initialize deck size, create ArrayList, and initialize count
   public final static int CARDS_IN_DECK = 81;
   public ArrayList<Card> deck;
   private int ct;

   /*
   Constructor that represents a fresh deck
   */
   public Deck(){
      freshDeck();
   }

   /*
   Copy constructor that creates all cards in a deck
   */
   public void freshDeck(){
      deck = new ArrayList<Card>(CARDS_IN_DECK);

      for (int number=0; number<3; number++){
         for (int shape=0; shape<3; shape++){
            for (int shading=0; shading<3; shading++) {
               for (int color=0; color<3; color++) {
                  deck.add(new Card(number, shape, shading, color));
               }
            }
         }
      }
    }

   /*
   method shuffle randomizes the order of the cards
   */ 
   public void shuffle()
   {
      int random;
      Card temp;
      Random r = new Random();
      for (int i = 0; i < deck.size(); i++)
      {
         random = r.nextInt(deck.size());
         temp = deck.get(i);
         deck.set(i,deck.get(random));
         deck.set(random,temp);
      }      
   }

   /*
   method isEmpty determines if the deck has cards in it
   */
   public boolean isEmpty()
   {
      return (deck.size() == 0);
   }

   /*
   method getTopCard
   deals a card, returns it, and removes it from the deck
   @return c
   */ 
   public Card getTopCard()
   {
      Card c = deck.remove(deck.size()-1);
      return c;
   }

   /*
   method toString
   turns the deck into a string and returns it
   @return str
   */
   public String toString(){
      String str="Current Deck:\n";
         for (int i=0; i < deck.size() ; i++){
          str+= deck.get(i).toString();
         }
      return str;
   }

   public ArrayList getCards() {
      return deck;
   }
}
```

Comment: You are trying to ask three questions in one thread. Edit your question and tackle one problem per question.

Comment: This is the 3rd question you've asked on this topic and I don't see any followups on the previous ones. Why won't you sort the problems one by one in an orderly fashion?